# L'emploi de « taper des mains »

Tags: expressions

Je sais que l’on dit parfois qu’on dit d’applaudir quelqu’un. J’ai aussi lu qu’on peut dire « il s’applaudit de son savoir-faire » au lieu de dire qu’il s’en vante. Si j’ai tout bien compris, on peut remplacer aussi « consentir à une chose » par « applaudir à quelque chose », même s’il n’y a pas de lien avec une pièce de théâtre ou quelque chose de semblable.

Cette question traite de la tournure « taper des mains ». Peut on la rendre transitive en ajoutant le mot *pour* ? Est-ce qu’elle peut s’élargir à d’autres emplois, comme *applaudir*, ou ce ne n’est qu’une façon montrer la joie qu’on a éprouvée lors d’une représentation ?

Answer (score 5):

L'expression "Taper des mains" ne peut pas être rendue transitive.

On ne peut pas "taper des mains" + COD (qui / quoi)

- "il tape des mains la pièce de théâtre" (incorrect)

Utilisez plutôt "applaudir" + COD.

- "Il applaudit la pièce de théâtre"

Par contre il est tout à fait correct de dire "taper des mains" + préposition (pour / par)

- "taper des mains pour marquer le rythme"

Answer (score 3):

« Taper des mains » n'est pas une expression française lorsqu'elle traduit *applaudir*, c'est un anglicisme que les mauvais traducteurs ne savent pas transcrire ; l'utiliser dans un français soutenu est mal venu.

Mécaniquement on tape *dans* ses mains.

Il y a des jeux d'enfants où l'on *tape dans ses mains* et *dans les mains* (parfois *sur les mains*) du ou des partenaires.

On peut aussi *taper des mains* ou *taper dans ses mains* pour attirer l'attention d'un groupe ou de quelqu'un.

« Taper des mains », cela arrive aussi dans l'excitation d'une surprise heureuse où l'applaudissement de contentement est très rapide et signifie que l'on est heureux de ce qui arrive ; dans ce cas on ne tape pas *dans* ses mains pour émettre un claquement bruyant, mais on *tape des mains* compulsivement pour traduire l'excitation qui surgit, le son n'est pas le même.

On *tape dans ses mains* (ou *des mains*) pour apprécier la qualité de l’acoustique d'une salle de spectacle.

*Ajout*

Parfois le public d'un spectacle *tape des mains* en rythme pour accompagner la musique.

---

*Suite aux commentaires*

*Apprécier*, dans ce cas-là n'a pas de rapport avec le prix de vente d'un bien.

- *Déterminer approximativement [l'acoustique d'une salle], par les sens*.
- *Porter un jugement favorable ; aimer, goûter* (avoir du *goût* pour l'excellence).

S'il faut utiliser la première définition pour *apprécier* une salle de spectacle (je suis en train d'apprécier), et que l'acoustique n'y est pas bonne, on ne dira pas "j'apprécie",  mais "je n'aime pas".

En général on utilise *apprécier* pour valoriser une sensation, une perception ;  on donne un jugement de valeur sur la qualité intrinsèque (pas sur le prix) de ce que l'on apprécie.

En revanche si quelqu’un fait une mauvaise plaisanterie à votre encontre, vous pouvez répondre "Je n'apprécie pas du tout, je ne goûte pas du tout cette blague".

<sup>(Références extraites du Robert)</sup>

Comment: Je crains d’avoir mal compris comment vous utilisez le mot *apprécier* dans une de vos phrases :

« On tape dans ses mains (ou des mains) pour apprécier la qualité de l’acoustique d'une salle de spectacle. »

Je pense que vous dites :

« On tape dans ses mains (ou des mains) pour mettre à l’épreuve l’acoustique d’une salle de spectacle, pour entendre si le bruit y retentit d’une jolie façon. »

Mais j’en doute fort. Pourriez-vous m’aider ?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin : « On tape dans ses mains (ou des mains) pour mettre à l’épreuve l’acoustique d’une salle de spectacle, pour entendre si le bruit y retentit d’une jolie façon. » votre interprétation me semble tout à fait correcte.